# Tuning couchbase using spring boot properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Does anyone know what should be correct spring boot properties to fine tune queryService in couchbase client. I am using spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase-reactive which uses couchbase-java-client 2.5.9 and couchbase-core-io 1.5.9

I am trying below properties but it is not working.

```
spring.couchbase.env.endpoints.queryservice.min-endpoints=5
spring.couchbase.env.endpoints.queryservice.max-endpoints=10
spring.couchbase.env.autorelease-after=5000
```

I can extend AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration to override properties but I would like to know if it is possible using spring boot properties.

Comment: Can you raise the issue that it is not working here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues